# Is there a way to action a trade in MetaTrader upon receiving data from an api?

Tags: metatrader4, metatrader5

I was just wondering if it was at all possible to execute/action a trade on the MetaTrader platform upon receiving a signal or response from an api.

If someone could just point me to some documentation or even assess the feasibility of this for me, I would be extremely grateful as I cant seem to find any relevant to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

according to
https://metaapi.cloud/docs/client/

1. under "Features" section,
   "... read historical market data..."
2. under "Current level of MetaTrader feature support" section,
   "... At this point we have good coverage of MetaTrader features except retrieving historical market data."
3. under "Feature limitations depending on offering type" section,
   "... historical market data is available for G1 and MT4 G2 only..."

can help to understand better whether data retrievals are supported?